# Handle POST request with params in the URL that contain backslashes

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, post, apache-camel

I do not have any control over the request/request type/headers/body.

I am creating a servlet that has to handle a POST request that will include multiple backslashes in the request url. (ex. www.servlet.com/path/foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4/foo5

I want to capture the value "foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4/foo5" and the number of backslashes in this can vary. The following solution will work for catching one "foo" but as soon as there are more, it will 404.

```
@Path("/path")
@WebService
public interface myService {    
    @POST
    @Path("/{resource}")
```

{resource} will only pass back "foo1", but if I can get past the 404 I can retrieve the full string by reading the request address.

**Is there a "wildcard" option for POST requests that could achieve something along the lines of**:

```
@Path("/path")
@WebService
public interface myService {    
    @POST
    @Path("/*")
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.3.Final/userguide/html/Using_Path.html

```
The @Path annotation is not limited to simple path expressions.
You also have the ability to insert regular expressions into @Path's value. For example:

@Path("/resources)
public class MyResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{var:.*}/stuff")
   public String get() {...}
}
The following GETs will route to the getResource() method:

GET /resources/stuff
GET /resources/foo/stuff
GET /resources/on/and/on/stuff
The format of the expression is:

"{" variable-name [ ":" regular-expression ] "}"
```

This is working for me now. My code looks like:

```
@Path("/path")
@WebService
public interface myService {    
    @POST
    @Path("/{resource: .*}")
```

It is catching everything but '?' and that might just be a regex thing. I will follow up with how to catch that character when I find a solution.

Edit: the '?' is being caught by @QueryParams so you can just parse it with something like

```
@QueryParam("param1") String param1
```